# Reading data from a sql server stored procedure in Node js?

Tags: javascript, sql-server, node.js

I am trying to get data returned from a sql server stored procedure and then fetch individual data by passing column names. For some reason, I am getting undefined when I pass column names. This is what I tried so far, what could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an issue with the signature of `execute` callback. It should be `function(result, returnValue)` where result will be `recordSet`

```
var updateMember = function( Country, BankID) {
   new sql.Request()
    .input('Country', sql.VarChar(50), Country)
    .input('BankID', sql.VarChar(50),  BankID)
    .execute('p_GetTransactionsStats').then(function(result, returnValue) {
      console.dir(result); // it should be [{},{}]

      for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        console.log("Merchantname :-" + result[i].MERCHANTNAME);
        console.log("Bankname :-" + result[i].BankName);
      }
  }).catch(function(err) {
    console.dir(err);
  });
};
```

**Second Solution**

Without changing the promise callback method, you can just tweak the way how you get value from result.

```
var updateMember = function( Country, BankID) {
   new sql.Request()
    .input('Country', sql.VarChar(50), Country)
    .input('BankID', sql.VarChar(50),  BankID)
    .execute('p_GetTransactionsStats').then(function(result) {
      console.dir(result); // it should be [[{},{}], returnValue:0]
      var records = result[0];

      for (var i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {
        console.log("Merchantname :-" + records[i].MERCHANTNAME);
        console.log("Bankname :-" + records[i].BankName);
      }
  }).catch(function(err) {
    console.dir(err);
  });
};
```

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Your results with is an *array or array*
Hence you need to access values as:

```
    for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        console.log("Merchantname :-" + result[0][i].MERCHANTNAME);
        console.log("Bankname :-" + result[0][i].BankName);
    }
```